# Hadoop Name node not listed while using jps command

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop. I installed hadoop by following link.
http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php

All installation was done.After that executed `start-all.sh` command.

Server started sucessfully. But when typing `jps` command it's not listing name node.Output as shown below.

```
6917 SecondaryNameNode
7185 NodeManager
6746 DataNode
7060 ResourceManager
7476 Jps
```

In hadoop-hduser-namenode-nag-VirtualBox.log log file shows fallowing output.

```
2015-02-06 11:40:27,287 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = nag-VirtualBox/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.4.1
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.4.1-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.4.1-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.10.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.4.1-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.4.1.jar:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar
STARTUP_MSG:   build = http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1604318; compiled by 'jenkins' on 2014-06-21T05:43Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_65
************************************************************/
2015-02-06 11:40:27,363 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2015-02-06 11:40:27,417 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: createNameNode []
2015-02-06 11:40:28,997 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2015-02-06 11:40:30,349 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2015-02-06 11:40:30,350 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2015-02-06 11:40:30,390 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: fs.defaultFS is hdfs://localhost:54310
2015-02-06 11:40:30,390 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Clients are to use localhost:54310 to access this namenode/service.
2015-02-06 11:40:31,834 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2015-02-06 11:40:33,600 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSUtil: Starting web server as: ${dfs.web.authentication.kerberos.principal}
2015-02-06 11:40:33,600 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSUtil: Starting Web-server for hdfs at: http://0.0.0.0:50070
2015-02-06 11:40:34,634 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2015-02-06 11:40:34,727 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLog: Http request log for http.requests.namenode is not defined
2015-02-06 11:40:35,129 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter)
2015-02-06 11:40:35,182 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context hdfs
2015-02-06 11:40:35,182 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2015-02-06 11:40:35,182 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context logs
2015-02-06 11:40:36,122 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter 'org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.AuthFilter' (class=org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.AuthFilter)
2015-02-06 11:40:36,165 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: addJerseyResourcePackage: packageName=org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.web.resources;org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.resources, pathSpec=/webhdfs/v1/*
2015-02-06 11:40:36,885 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 50070
2015-02-06 11:40:36,886 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2015-02-06 11:40:39,807 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter: 'signature.secret' configuration not set, using a random value as secret
2015-02-06 11:40:40,332 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50070
2015-02-06 11:40:40,602 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Only one image storage directory (dfs.namenode.name.dir) configured. Beware of dataloss due to lack of redundant storage directories!
2015-02-06 11:40:40,602 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Only one namespace edits storage directory (dfs.namenode.edits.dir) configured. Beware of dataloss due to lack of redundant storage directories!
2015-02-06 11:40:40,905 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsLock is fair:true
2015-02-06 11:40:41,250 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.HostFileManager: read includes:
HostSet(
)
2015-02-06 11:40:41,250 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.HostFileManager: read excludes:
HostSet(
)
2015-02-06 11:40:41,281 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
2015-02-06 11:40:41,281 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check=true
2015-02-06 11:40:41,298 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
2015-02-06 11:40:41,298 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2015-02-06 11:40:41,329 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: 2.0% max memory 966.7 MB = 19.3 MB
2015-02-06 11:40:41,329 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
2015-02-06 11:40:41,420 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
2015-02-06 11:40:41,421 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 1
2015-02-06 11:40:41,421 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
2015-02-06 11:40:41,421 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
2015-02-06 11:40:41,421 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
2015-02-06 11:40:41,421 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: shouldCheckForEnoughRacks  = false
2015-02-06 11:40:41,421 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
2015-02-06 11:40:41,421 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer        = false
2015-02-06 11:40:41,421 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxNumBlocksToLog          = 1000
2015-02-06 11:40:41,485 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = hduser (auth:SIMPLE)
2015-02-06 11:40:41,485 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
2015-02-06 11:40:41,485 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = true
2015-02-06 11:40:41,485 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
2015-02-06 11:40:41,523 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
2015-02-06 11:40:41,994 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map INodeMap
2015-02-06 11:40:41,994 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2015-02-06 11:40:41,995 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: 1.0% max memory 966.7 MB = 9.7 MB
2015-02-06 11:40:41,995 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^20 = 1048576 entries
2015-02-06 11:40:42,025 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
2015-02-06 11:40:42,076 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map cachedBlocks
2015-02-06 11:40:42,076 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2015-02-06 11:40:42,077 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: 0.25% max memory 966.7 MB = 2.4 MB
2015-02-06 11:40:42,077 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^18 = 262144 entries
2015-02-06 11:40:42,079 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
2015-02-06 11:40:42,079 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
2015-02-06 11:40:42,079 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
2015-02-06 11:40:42,089 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache on namenode is enabled
2015-02-06 11:40:42,089 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache will use 0.03 of total heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis
2015-02-06 11:40:42,110 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map NameNodeRetryCache
2015-02-06 11:40:42,110 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2015-02-06 11:40:42,110 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 966.7 MB = 297.0 KB
2015-02-06 11:40:42,110 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
2015-02-06 11:40:42,154 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AclConfigFlag: ACLs enabled? false
2015-02-06 11:40:42,262 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Lock on /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 2313@nag-VirtualBox
2015-02-06 11:40:42,279 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Encountered exception loading fsimage
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode/current/VERSION (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.StorageInfo.readPropertiesFile(StorageInfo.java:241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.StorageInfo.readProperties(StorageInfo.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:891)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:638)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1424)
2015-02-06 11:40:42,347 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50070
2015-02-06 11:40:42,465 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NameNode metrics system...
2015-02-06 11:40:42,466 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system stopped.
2015-02-06 11:40:42,466 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system shutdown complete.
2015-02-06 11:40:42,467 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode/current/VERSION (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.StorageInfo.readPropertiesFile(StorageInfo.java:241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.StorageInfo.readProperties(StorageInfo.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:891)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:638)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1424)
2015-02-06 11:40:42,496 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2015-02-06 11:40:42,602 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at nag-VirtualBox/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Comment: Could you open all the Hadoop Web Interfaces ?

Comment: `(Permission denied)`

Comment: Yes...SecondaryNameNode accessed with http://localhost:50090/status.jsp

Comment: Yes...i am accessing all hadoop web interfaces except name node

Comment: then try to stop it all by ./stop-all.sh and restart it again

Answer (score 1):

You should give the launch-user privileges.
Furthermore, it doesn't support three or more namenodes.

Accordingly, if you set three nodes, the hadoop-xxx-namenode-yyy.log would like this:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected exactly 2 NameNodes in namespace 'mycluster'. Instead, got only 3 (NN ids were 'nn1','nn2','nn3'`

Answer (score 0):

Check `/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode/current/VERSION` permissions

Answer (score -1):

The first step for troubleshooting is restarting daemons. I would suggest you go ahead and do this and see if it's up.

```
sudo service hadoop-master stop
sudo service hadoop-master start
hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
sudo jps
```